# React router link doesn't refresh automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click a Link, the url changes, but the content of the page doesn't change unless I manually refresh my browser. Why is this? I use React Router v5.

Here's my code in App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={tempStyles}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact component={Quiz} path="/quiz" />
          <Route exact component={Home} path="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And here's my Home.js

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/quiz">
          Take the quiz
        </Link>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: This usually happens when you have nested routes and are passing `exact` prop inside the Route component. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had the same problem and it turns out there should be only one  component.
In your case try removing the  Component from Home.js.

```
function Home() {
   return (
      <div>
         <Link to="/quiz">
          Take the quiz
         </Link>
      </div> 
   );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wherever you defined your routes make path `exact={true}`, this will fix your problem.
The main problem is that we often don't use `exact={true}` when defining routes and as a consequence the actual component does not renders until refreshed.

> For ex -  Suppose I defined for `'/path'` render `TempComponent` and
> for `'path/actual'` render `ActualComponent`. So what happen if I
> don't set `exact={true}` for `'/path'` and `'/path/actual'`,
> `react-router` will render `TempComponent` for `'/path/actual'`
> because it is matching the url `'/path'` even though partially if we
> set `exact={true}` then for `'/path/actual'` it'll not render
> `TempComponent` instead it'll render `ActualComponent`